# How to show and hide property key and value based on condition in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have following class with three properties.

```
public class Item
{
    public float a { get; set; }
    public float b { get; set; }
    public float c { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the method where I need a return type of class Item which should not contain the default or null value. How can I achieve this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Item> callingprogram = CallIngprogram1();

        callingprogram2(callingprogram);
    }

    private static List<Item> callingprogram2(List<Item> paramss )
    {
    if (paramss[0].c == 0.0)
        {
        // return the list which should not contain the property C. IF the value is null or default value that property value should not return
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static List<Item> CallIngprogram1()
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
        list.Add(new Item
        {
            a = 1,
            b = 3
            // c value is not assign so it contain the default value
        });
        return list;
    }

}
```

Suppose I assign a value to all the three property all three property should return. If I don't assign any value to any of the property name as well as value should not return.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. the default value is not different than explicitly assigning `0.0` to property.

Comment: my concerns is if I assign a value to a and b property the return type should contain only a and b parameter. I don't need c in the return value since it has the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of float in c# is 0. You can put this logic in your callingprogram2(). If all values are assigned it will return a,b,c and if c is not assigned it will return a,b:

**EDIT:**

```
    private static List<dynamic> callingprogram2(List<Item> paramss)
    {
        dynamic newList = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (var item in paramss)
        {
            dynamic dObject = new ExpandoObject();
            dObject.a = item.a;
            dObject.b = item.b;
            if (item.c != 0.0)
            {
                dObject.c = item.c;
            }
            newList.Add(dObject);
        }

        return newList;
    }
```

Comment: my concerns is if I assign a value to a and b property the return type should contain only a and b parameter. I don't need c in the return value as well as key in the list.since it has the default value. I don't need a null return value.

Comment: @San Jaisy In c# you cannot remove properties at runtime since the metadata is fixed in assembly. If you need to create dynamic properties then you should use ExpandoObject

Comment: Can U show me how can I achieve this by Expandobject

Comment: Thanks Dragon lord i need in this way ....

Comment: @San Jaisy It was a pleasure to help you.. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Until you defined a class, any instance of it will contains all the properties. The question is how do you use this instance. May be you need to change the logic that uses instances.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Please can you elaborate with sample. But my concerns is if I assign a value to a and b property the return type should contain only a and b parameter. I don't need c in the return value since it has the default value

Comment: @ San Jaisy If I understand your question right, in your example you want to return an Item that just doesn't contain the property C. Until you return an instance of class Item it will contain all the properties defined in this class. So what you can do is to return dynamic object like in the sample above.